# How to get multiselect DropDownList items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I use FineUI DropDownList control and this DropDownList is EnableMultiSelect. At "Show Selected Items" button's click event I want to show the selected items information. In my code shows a  problem:

> "Can not convert type 'FineUI.ListItem' to
>   'Systm.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'".

How to solve it?

The button click code like these:

```
protected void btnGetSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string result="Selected informations：";
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.SelectedItemArray)
            {
                result = result + item.Value;

            } 
            labResult.Text = result;
        }
        else
            labResult.Text = "No SelectedItem";
    }
```

Page source code:

```
<FineUI:pagemanager ID="PageManager1" runat="server" />
<FineUI:simpleform ID="SimpleForm1" BodyPadding="5px" runat="server" Width="450px" EnableCollapse="true"
    ShowBorder="True" Title="Simple DropdownList（AutoPostBack）" ShowHeader="True">
    <Items>
        <FineUI:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" EnableMultiSelect="true" EnableEdit="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Label="试验：">
        </FineUI:DropDownList>
        <FineUI:Button  runat ="server"  Text="Select[item6]" OnClick="btnSelectItem6_Click" CssClass="marginr" ></FineUI:Button>
        <FineUI:Button  Text="Show Selected Items" OnClick="btnGetSelection_Click" runat="server" ></FineUI:Button>
    </Items>
</FineUI:simpleform>
<FineUI:label runat="server" ID="labResult"></FineUI:label>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me edit the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your loop with the ListItem `foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.SelectedItemArray)` C# handles `ListItem` as a ListItem from `Systm.Web.UI.WebControls` but `DropDownList1.SelectedItemArray` is an array full of ListItems from `FineUI`.

So you have two classes with the Name `ListItem` and C# gets "confused". 
You can solve this by changing your for loop slightly by adding the path of the class.

```
foreach (FineUI.ListItem item in DropDownList1.SelectedItemArray)
```

I checked the documentation of FineUI and the ListItems have the Value and Text members that you use in the loop so no further changes are needed.

Comment: I got it. Thanks  for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with type conversion.Your control has `FineUI.ListItem` and you are trying to convert them to `Systm.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem`. In your foreach loop, you have to correct type.

```
protected void btnGetSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string result="Selected informations：";
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            foreach (FineUI.ListItem item in DropDownList1.SelectedItemArray)
            {
                result = result + item.Value;

            } 
            labResult.Text = result;
        }
        else
            labResult.Text = "No SelectedItem";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I solve the problem by using your method.